# How to write Laravel Eloquent whereBetween method with two columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to write the following query in eloquent format:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` where timestamp_col1 AND timestamp_col2 BETWEEN 
'2018-07-23 11:45:25' and '2018-07-23 14:45:25'
```

By using default method from eloquent I was able to write the query in following format:

```
$this->getEntity()
     ->whereBetween('timestamp_col1', [$start, $end])
     ->orWhereBetween('timestamp_col2', [$start, $end])
     ->get();
```

But disadvantage of writing in above format is that I have to manually specify 
**start and end timestamp** individually for both columns. Is there any other way to achieve this or do I have to use `whereRaw()` method? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify `$start` and `$end` timestamps manually. You just need to convert `$start` and `$end` values to timestamps or proper datetime format using Php date function as mentioned below:

```
$start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start));
$end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end));
$this->getEntity()
     ->whereBetween('timestamp_col1', [$start, $end])
     ->orWhereBetween('timestamp_col2', [$start, $end])
     ->get();
```

Comment: "You do not need to specify $start and $end timestamps manually" while referring this i am already trying to state this implicitly in question that $start and $end by default are of timestamp type but problem is that i have to pass a range that falls directly between two columns like A TO B, but right now i am doing it colum1 from X to A or column2  Y to B

Comment: In that case, whereRaw() method is the only option you have.

Answer (score 0):

You *have* to use two separate `WHERE BETWEEN` clauses.

`where timestamp_col1 AND timestamp_col2 BETWEEN [...]` is not doing what you think it's doing.
The query returns all rows where the first column evaluates to `true` and only applies the `WHERE BETWEEN` clause to the second column.

Take a look at this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6fe15/1

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?